# How can I programmatically get the ACCESS_TOKEN from Instagram?

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram-api

What I want to do is

1. have users authenticate my Instagram app on my website - this I implemented
2. with cron tasks, I want to pull data e.g daily and

   1. either display it on the website (in this case, the app is a widget) OR
   2. save it locally so another App can parse it (in this case, the app is basically a data importer)

Looking through IG developer documentation, I'm not sure if either case is even possible (though sense would indicate that they should be)?

What I'm stuck at is how to create an ACCESS_TOKEN from IG using my developer/app credentials?

Currently, I'm generating the LoginUrl, and if I use it in the browser, since I'm logged in, I get properly redirected (so the rest of the code and app setup seems to be in order).

When I try to connect from the app, I'm not logged in and the response is not the code, but a Login Form. First thing that came to mind was that I can somehow log in directly, but I couldn't find any API for that (and it seems IG doesn't want you to do it since apparently you need to fake cookies and whatnot).

I can't seem to find any other solutions so any help (even "we've tried this, it's not possible anymore because Instagram") is appreciated :)

Comment: There's two ways: manually or using the oficial python Instagram Client.

Comment: Do you have any links to doing it manually?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to find an official Python IG Client, just one that is no longer maintained.

Comment: Yes, I do. I'll search in my bitbucket repo and then I'll be back here.

Comment: Abbreviation for Instagram is IG

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can just need to force IG to give you an access token by going to:

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_WITH_PROTOCOL_HERE]&response_type=token

More details here: http://www.projectmayhem.co.uk/blog/creating-an-instagram-feed-for-umbraco/ and remember

> At the end of the redirect URL you should see access_token= with your
>   access token. Guard this with your life!